# SharePoint:DateTimeControl inside ruins Calendar navigation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a simple Visual Web part in SharePoint 2010. It has only one control:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtCalendarStartDate"  runat="server"  />
```

I have created a Calendar and added this webpart on top of the Calendar. After that Calendar navigation buttons stop to work. They do post back and add "&date=" param. But Calendar does not change it next/prev month.

Why DateTimeControl breaks Calendar? And how to avoid it?

Thank you

**EDIT:**
I have found a cause and solution but it looks very inelegant :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c1809295-2497-4ea4-a42a-4e4ed02e627b/why-does-my-custom-c-web-part-conflict-with-the-sp-calendar-web-parts-functionality

Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any other solution than http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c1809295-2497-4ea4-a42a-4e4ed02e627b/why-does-my-custom-c-web-part-conflict-with-the-sp-calendar-web-parts-functionality

It's not very elegant but it works just fine.